# How to test commands in Angular-CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to create my own small project, which will represent a CLI with basic number of my own commands. This project is based on Angular-CLI.

And my question is: how can I test my own commands? Or how can I test Angular-CLI commands, first of all?

My idea was to copy e2e and serve commands, after that pack all my new commands to e2e runner and then test it... But I'm not really sure about this way.

Couldn't you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Go to the [`scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts) section of the `package.json` file and edit the scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own scripts in `package.json--> scripts folder.`

Example :-

```
 "port4900": "ng serve --port 4900",
```

`npm run port4900` if you execute this command it will your app on 4900 port insted of default 4200

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I mean: how can I test commands? for example: how can I test command build... and so on